# How can fonts cause OpenGL out of memory error?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem with my AppWidget. Some users on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus S who have Android 4.0 are reporting broken fonts in stock launcher.

I had the phone connected to ADB to see the logs and I found there these errors multiple times:

```
OpenGLRenderer is out of memory!
```

Is there a way to optimize AppWidget to be less memory demanding for OpenGL renderer?

Is it sufficient to reduce the levels of the view tree?

Originally posted at: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Aoxf_hWIQ24

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Android engineers have found that very large font sizes can cause low-memory conditions in the font cache in Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.  They are working on ways to more effectively cache fonts that require a lot of memory.  No workaround was proposed at this time.

To be less demanding, reduce font size.

Comment: Note that this is an issue only on GPUs that use a deferred rendering architecture. For instance, a phone using a Tegra2 or Tegra3 GPU will NOT have this problem.